# how to declare the scalar variable "@CIN" in this code

Tags: c#

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        // Open the connection using the connection string.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-6Q836P8JQ1C\oby;Initial Catalog=Etudiant;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Abscence (CIN,Heure_debut,Heure_fin,Date)";
        sqlQuery += "VALUES ('CIN', 'Heure_debut', 'Heure_fin', 'Date')";
            // Insert into the Sql table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CIN", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CIN"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Heure_debut", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Heure_fin",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column2"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);   
                }
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                com.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me it's my baccalaureate Project

Comment: Parameter names should start with `@`.

Comment: I don't understand this type of comments `Please help me it's my baccalaureate Project `. Why do you think we should help you.For ex,  I wouldn't  want to have a team mate  (maybe in the near future) who doesn't able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First in your query you don't have parameters, also there is no need to write the query as concatanation of 2 strings:

```
string sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO 
                       Abscence (CIN,Heure_debut,Heure_fin,Date)
                    VALUES 
                      (@CIN, @Heure_debut, @Heure_fin, @Date)";
```

You can write string on more than one line using symbol @, before starting the string `@""`.

To declare parameter again you are using @ symbol. When you add them with value it should be written like this:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIN", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CIN"].Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heure_debut",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heure_fin",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column2"].Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
```

Comment: i do this but there a new problem  "Additional information: The parameterized query '(@CIN int,@Heure_debut nvarchar(4000),@Heure_fin nvarchar(4000),' expects the parameter '@Heure_debut', which was not supplied."

Comment: if you look closely my code you will see that you should not have '' before and after the parameter.

Comment: i copied your solution but the same problem   Additional information: The parameterized query '(@CIN int,@Heure_debut nvarchar(4000),@Heure_fin nvarchar(4000),' expects the parameter '@Heure_debut', which was not supplied

Comment: you can use debug you know it ?

Comment: yes  but when i click in the bottom of save (button2) the program stop working and show me th Additional information